# How can I display the video stream of an action camera to an image box using capture of emgu cv c#?

Tags: c#, streaming, emgucv, ip-camera

I can play the following link in vlc media player:

```
rtsp://192.168.42.1:554/live
```

But when I use the same link inside my capture initialization I can't get anything and my image box is displaying nothing.

```
private void Form1_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.42.1/live"); 
  Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrame); 
} 

public void ProcessFrame (object sender, EventArgs arg) 
{ 
  imageBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); 
}
```

Comment: Please show ([edit]) us what you've attempted so far within `c#` to try and get this working.  We can't help you effectively without some idea of what you're attempting, and what's gone wrong.

Comment: @gravity this is what i have so far.. Basic capture initialization..

`private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.42.1/live");
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
        }

        public void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            imageBox1.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
}`

Comment: @gravity I can't find any solution online and i can't get any idea why it isn't capturing something. I thought the issue was because of ffmpeg h264? Please help..

Comment: You would normally want to [edit] your question, as I originally suggested, and put your sample code in the question.  I've done this for you this time, but please read [ask] and consider looking through the "Related" questions below, on the right side bar, as well.  They may help some as well.

Comment: @gravity wow, thank you.. :)